# ansible: gcp_compute_disk - problem creating disk from a snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I am new to Ansible and I am trying to figure out how to create a GCP disk from a GCP snapshot, using the `gcp_compute_disk` module. I am using the following documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_disk_module.html
I created the playbook below, but it only creates an empty new disk, not a disk from the snapshot. My ansible version is 2.9.20.

```
- name: Create GCP snapshots
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
      gcp_project: test-project
      gcp_cred_kind: serviceaccount
      gcp_cred_file: /etc/ansible/keys/ansible-test-project-service-account-key.json
      zone: "us-central1-a"
      region: "us-central1"
      instancename: "test-instance"
      snapshot:
        selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-project/global/snapshots/test-snapshot1

  tasks:
  
   - name: create data disk from a snapshot
     gcp_compute_disk:
       name: "{{ instancename }}-data-1"
       description: "{{ instancename }}-data-1"
       zone: "{{ zone }}"
       project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
       auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
       service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
       source_snapshot: "{{ snapshot }}"
       labels:
         usage: test-label
       type: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-project/zones/us-central1-b/diskTypes/pd-standard"
       state: present
     register: disk_data
```

I have also tried to create the snapshot first with `gcp_compute_snapshot`, then registered that snapshot (`register: disksnapshot`), and then used that dictionary to reference the snapshot (`source_snapshot: "{{ disksnapshot }}"`). The result is the same.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Thor welcome to SO. I don't understand your question -- there is no such property `source_snapshot` listed on the very documentation page you linked to, so why would you expect you can just make up a property and have it work? You will also want to read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page which explains that without the error message you are getting from your non-working code, no one can help you out. Good luck

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel. My first post and I already include the wrong link (-;. I mistakenly posted the link to the `gcp_compute_snapshot` module, while I am actually using the `gcp_compute_disk` module. I have fixed my original post accordingly. In regards to the error message: The ansible-playbook executes without error and a disk does get created in GCP. But it is a new empty disk, while the expected behavior is to create a disk from a GCP snapshot.